# Apply a regex only to the first word of a phrase (defined with spaces)

Tags: r, regex

I have this regex to separate letters from numbers (and symbols) of a word: `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=([[0-9]|[:punct:]]))`. My test string is: `"CALLE15 CRA22"`.

I want to apply this regex only to the first word of that sentence (the word is defined with spaces). Namely, I want apply that only to `"CALLE15"`.

One solution is split the string (sentence) into words and then apply the regex to the first word, but I want to do all in one regex. Other solution is to use r `stringr::str_replace() (or sub())` that replace only the first match, but I need `stringr::str_replace_all (or gsub())` for other reasons.

What I need is to insert a space between the two that I do with the replacement function. The outcome I want is `"CALLE 15 CRA22"` and with the posibility of `"CALLE15 CRA 22"`. I try a lot of positions for the space and nothing, neither the `^` at the beginning.

https://rubular.com/r/7dxsHdOA3avTdX

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: *"The outcome I want is `"CALLE 15 CRA22"` and with the po[s]sibility of `"CALLE15 CRA 22"`"* I am confused. You stress that you want to apply a regex only to the first word, but then still want to (optionally?) apply that regex to the second word? Can you clarify? I also don't understand what you mean by needing to use `str_replace_all` "for other reasons".

Comment: The possibility (excuses for the type) to choose to which word I apply that regex (to the first or the second word). But that's just an option. I use str_replace_all for cases such `"CALLE15A20 CRA22"` with desired outcome equal to `"CALLE 15A 20 CRA22"`. Those are adresses in my country.

Comment: I'm getting more and more confused. How does `"CALLE15A20 CRA22"` become `"CALLE 15A 20 CRA22"`? This seems very different from the example you give in your main post. What are the rules for splitting the first word into *three* parts? I don't understand what you mean by *"The possibility [...] to choose to which word I apply that regex"*; so you want a function of some sort with a parameter that selects the word?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. The last example wasn't uselful. The general rule is to group letters with letters, numbers with numbers, etc., and separate them with spaces. Each of these, except symbols, are a different field in the address: from `CLL.6 N 5-74NORTE` to `CLL . 6 N 5 - 74 NORTE`. Because there are so many exceptions, my approach was to resolve this "word" by "word": first, fix the `CLL.6` to `CLL . 6` to  `CLL` (type of road field) and  `6` (street number field), etc. This led me to the title question: separate `CLL.6` or the first word, without modify the rest `N 5-74NORTE`.

Comment: *"The general rule is to group letters with letters, numbers with numbers, etc., and separate them with spaces."* But that's not consistent with your previous example where `"CALLE15A20 CRA22"` became `"CALLE 15A 20 CRA22"`! In `"15A"`you have grouped numbers with letters.

Comment: You are right.  That example was an error of using `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=([[0-9]|[:punct:]]))` with `str_replace_all`, because the matches never overlap and the regex not specify a number next to letters in both sides. For that reason the result was from `CALLE15A20` (alone) to `CALLE 15A 20`. I was trying to thinking in how to resolve that to, but that is another question, so simply omit that.

Comment: This resolve the problem from `CALLE 15A 20` to  `CALLE 15 A 20`:   `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=([[0-9]|[:punct:]]))|(?<=([[0-9]|[:punct:]]))(?=[a-zA-Z])`. https://rubular.com/r/uNejYalEli2DCK

Comment: I've made an edit to my post, please take a look. We can reproduce the expected output using `str_split` to split words from digits (and digits from words).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, your patience and your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure about your problem statement (see my comment above), but the following reproduces your expected output and uses `str_replace_all`

```
ss <- "CALLE15 CRA22"
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(ss, "^([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)(\\s.+)$", "\\1 \\2\\3")
#[1] "CALLE 15 CRA22"
```

---

### Update

To reproduce the output of the sample string from the comment above

```
ss <- "CLL.6 N 5-74NORTE"

pat <- c(
    "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?![A-Za-z])",
    "(?<![A-Za-z])(?=[A-Za-z])",
    "(?<=[0-9])(?![0-9])",
    "(?<![0-9])(?=[0-9])")

library(stringr)
str_split(ss, sprintf("(%s)", paste(pat, collapse = "|"))) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    .[nchar(trimws(.)) > 0] %>%
    paste(collapse = " ")
#[1] "CLL . 6 N 5 - 74 NORTE"
```